# C# Code runs too slow. Needs multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am finding it difficult to make the following code (which uses the Pastel Accounting SDK) go any faster. Currently it takes a few hours to update :(

Some background information:
The code selects records from a local database, then updates 3 separate databases all on the same server. When updating the 3 other databases, it does them in single updates.

After updating the records in all 3 database, it them updates the local database with a fresh copy of the data.

It's basically updating prices, and saving the old price.

I tried implementing Multi-threading, but could not get it to work :(

Here is my code:

```
public string ExportPrices(bool _restorePrices = false)
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logs/PriceUpdateErrorList.txt"), "Error Messages" + Environment.NewLine);

            var db = new UniStockContext();
            //fetch all databases to export to
            IList<AccDatabase> accDBCol = db.AccDatabases.Where(x => (x.Active == true) && (x.Deleted == false)).ToList();
            //fetch all inventory list
            IList<Domain.Tables.Inventory> inventoryDBCol = db.Inventories.Where(x => (x.Active == true) && (x.Deleted == false)).ToList();

            if (inventoryDBCol.Count > 0)
            {
                //string xmlResult = "<InventoryExportResponse>";
                //loop through databases and export
                foreach (AccDatabase accDB in accDBCol)
                {
                    //check database type and call appropriate accounting system method
                    if ((accDB.Type == AccDatabaseType.SageEvolution) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(accDB.EvolutionCommon))
                    {
                        //////////////////////////////////////////
                        //////////////Sage Evolution//////////////
                        //////////////////////////////////////////
                        foreach (AccDatabase accDB2 in accDBCol)
                        {
                            if ((accDB2.Type == AccDatabaseType.SageEvolution) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(accDB2.EvolutionCommon))
                            {
                                //pass db and common db to export method for Sage Evolution
                                try
                                {
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accDB.DBName))
                                    {
                                        inventoryDBCol = _sageInventory.ExportPrices(accDB, accDB2, inventoryDBCol, restorPrices: false);//this call updates 13000 records
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception exExportPrices)
                                {
                                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logs/_sageInventoryExportPricesCallError.txt"), exExportPrices.ToString());
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //end foreach

                //return (xmlResult + "</InventoryExportResponse>");
            }

            UpdatePricesFromInventoryListBulk(_inventoryCollection);//this call will update 40000 records in local DB.

            return "Stock prices synched to accounting system!";
        }

public void UpdatePricesFromInventoryListBulk(IList<Domain.Tables.Inventory> invList)
        {
            var db = new UniStockContext();
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            foreach (var inventory in invList)
            {
                Domain.Tables.Inventory _inventory = db.Inventories
                                                    .Single(x => x.InventoryID == inventory.InventoryID);

                if (inventory.Cost.HasValue)
                    _inventory.Cost = inventory.Cost.Value;
                else
                    _inventory.Cost = 0;

                foreach (var inventoryPrices in inventory.AccInventoryPrices)
                {
                    foreach (var _inventoryPrices in _inventory.AccInventoryPrices)
                    {
                        if (_inventoryPrices.AccInventoryPriceID == inventoryPrices.AccInventoryPriceID)
                        {
                            _inventoryPrices.ApplyDiscount = inventoryPrices.ApplyDiscount;
                            _inventoryPrices.ApplyMarkup = inventoryPrices.ApplyMarkup;
                            if (inventoryPrices.Price.HasValue)
                                _inventoryPrices.Price = inventoryPrices.Price.Value;
                            else
                                _inventoryPrices.Price = _inventory.Cost;

                            if (inventoryPrices.OldPrice.HasValue)
                            {
                                _inventoryPrices.OldPrice = inventoryPrices.OldPrice;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                db.Inventories.Attach(_inventory);
                db.Entry(_inventory).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Dispose();
        }
```

I've edited my code to add multi-threading. But the process does not seem to run at all.

```
    public string ExportPrices(bool _restorePrices = false)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logs/PriceUpdateErrorList.txt"), "Error Messages" + Environment.NewLine);

        var db = new UniStockContext();
        //fetch all databases to export to
        IList<AccDatabase> accDBCol = db.AccDatabases.Where(x => (x.Active == true) && (x.Deleted == false)).ToList();
        //fetch all inventory list
        IList<Domain.Tables.Inventory> inventoryDBCol = db.Inventories.Where(x => (x.Active == true) && (x.Deleted == false)).ToList();

        if (inventoryDBCol.Count > 0)
        {
            //string xmlResult = "<InventoryExportResponse>";
            //loop through databases and export
            foreach (AccDatabase accDB in accDBCol)
            {
                //check database type and call appropriate accounting system method
                if ((accDB.Type == AccDatabaseType.SageEvolution) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(accDB.EvolutionCommon))
                {
                    //////////////////////////////////////////
                    //////////////Sage Evolution//////////////
                    //////////////////////////////////////////
                    foreach (AccDatabase accDB2 in accDBCol)
                    {
                        if ((accDB2.Type == AccDatabaseType.SageEvolution) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(accDB2.EvolutionCommon))
                        {
                            //pass db and common db to export method for Sage Evolution
                            try
                            {
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accDB.DBName))
                                {
                                    Thread thread = new Thread(()
                                        => inventoryDBCol = _sageInventory.ExportPrices(accDB, accDB2, inventoryDBCol, restorPrices: false)
                                        );
                                    thread.Start();

                                    //inventoryDBCol = _sageInventory.ExportPrices(accDB, accDB2, inventoryDBCol, restorPrices: false);//this call updates 13000 records
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception exExportPrices)
                            {
                                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logs/_sageInventoryExportPricesCallError.txt"), exExportPrices.ToString());
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //end foreach

            //return (xmlResult + "</InventoryExportResponse>");
        }

        UpdatePricesFromInventoryListBulk(inventoryDBCol);//this call will update 40000 records in local DB.

        return "Stock prices synched to accounting system!";
    }
```

Comment: When you profiled your code, where were the slow parts?

Comment: At a high level can you explain what `UpdatePricesFromInventoryListBulk` is trying to achieve?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something descriptive of the problem you're having or question you're asking. You've simply repeated the information that is already available in the tags. Your title should be clear enough about the content of your post to be useful to a future user of the site who is scanning a list of search results. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to profile / debug. I'm developing the code locally. then testing on the clients server as their Accounting databases have licenses that can only work on their server. I suspect it takes long when updating each product to the accounting database.

Comment: "I tried implementing Multi-threading,"-  and there is no trace of that. Go and try it. It DOES work - once upon a time I was hitting a db server with around 1 million sql statements per I think minute from a then 96 core machine using around 300 threads. So, yes, it does work.

Comment: @mjwills UpdatePricesFromInventoryListBulk  is simply updating the local database with old prices. This is the same records that it fetches to update the external accounting databases

Comment: @TomTom However multi-threading won´t neccessarily lead to faster performance. It *can*, if you know how to do it. But 20 threads on a single- or even quad-code machine won´t do anything.

Comment: I just need to make the _sageInventory.ExportPrices(accDB, accDB2, inventoryDBCol, restorPrices: false);//this call updates 13000 records  line execute in a separate thread. So it will basically run in 3 threads. But don't know how to add a method call to ThreadStart with parms.

Comment: @TomTom Additional threads aren't going to help you perform IO bound work any faster.  You can perform the operations in parallel just as effectively by performing the operations asynchronously, with no need for threading.  Threading would only be useful in processing the results, if said processing was actually expensive, and even then, only up to the number of logical processors on your machine, any more only results in wasted overhead.

Comment: Yeah, except that was once upon a time - BEFORE async/await existed in dotnet. Any more smart comments based on your lack of understanding of time being not a constant? Also, believe me, when you put a half am million USD database server in the backend then you are not IO bound.

Comment: Consider a single large SQL update rather than a large number of individual updates.

Comment: @mjwills  It's not possible to do a single SQL update as I have to use the Pastel Accounting SDK.

Comment: `db.SaveChanges();` looks like Entity Framework rather than some other SDK? Unless I am mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

The code, as written with `Thread.Start(...)` **does** likely work, but `Thread.Start` just starts the process - if it was taking hours before, it's probably going to take hours now. Adding a thread to the mix won't suddenly make the databases complete the work faster.

It's likely the the issue is in the `.ExportPrices(...)` function, but you say you can't profile it, so we'll never know. If *you* can't use any tools to find out **where** the program runs slowly, then *we* can't know **where** the program runs slowly.

To me, anything that wraps a request that handles thousands of rows between multiple databases in a single function is not thinking well about the work going on. The operations that are taking place are key, and because they're not included in the question, *we can't possibly know* if they're the issue or not.

You need to *carefully consider* the database operations you're wrapping. If that's where the performance issue is, then it's likely you need to rework what's in that algorithm, not what's here in this short, simple function.

If the database operations aren't hitting any one database more than once, then it's possible you could also use `Thread.Start`  to run those operations and use `Thread.Join` to wait on their completion,  but this will only allow more than one to run at once, not reduce the time it takes to complete one.

Comment: I hear you.  I think because the Pastel SDK does not allow batch updates, I have to update 40k products 1 at a time. This is where the lag is happening. I'm considering other options, like maybe doing batch updates with raw SQL.